# Finding Root Url and Subsites Url In Collection

Tags: c#

I have a strong typed list string collection consistenting of root level sites sometimes represented at the domain level, however sometimes not. For example:

```
http://x.com
http://x.com/y
http://x.com/y/w
http://x.com/y/z
http://a.com/b/c
http://a.com/b/c/d
http://a.com/b/c/e
```

I need to convert the string collection to a collection of strongly typed custom objects, such as the below:

```
public class UrlObject
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public List<UrlObject> subUrls { get; set; }
}
```

The amount of characters and slashes in the "Parent" url can vary, I am curious if there is a way that building a collection that allows flexible for the size of the "Parent".

The expected output of this method would be a list collection with two objects, represented below:

object 1

```
Parent - http://x.com
subUrls- http://x.com/y,
         http://x.com/y/w,
         http://x.com/y/z
```

object 2

```
Parent: http://a.com/b/c
subUrls-http://a.com/b/c/d, 
        http://a.com/b/c/e
```

Comment: There is already an entire built in class to do this, [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I am not sure I understand what you are asking.  Can you include a sample output in your question?

Comment: I added the expected output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class that already exists in .NET that will make your life a lot easier: [`System.Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx).  Instead of your custom class, you can create a "conatiner" class like this:

```
public class UriContainer
{
    public Uri Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Uri> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You can easily turn a collection of string urls into `Uri` objects with a little bit of LINQ:

```
var urlStringList = new List<string>()
{
    "http://x.com",
    "http://x.com/y",
    "http://x.com/y/w",
    "http://x.com/y/z",
    "http://a.com/b/c",
    "http://a.com/b/c/d",
    "http://a.com/b/c/e"
};

IEnumerable<Uri> uris = urlStringList.Select(x => new Uri(x));
```

From there you can `GroupBy()` the `Host` property, then inside each group, `OrderBy()` the `Segments.Length` property.  Then take the `First()` one (this is the one with the least segments aka the "parent" per your example), then you take the rest of them as the "children":

```
var containerList = new List<UriContainer>();           

foreach(var groupedUri in uris.GroupBy(x => x.Host))
{
    var sorted = groupedUri.OrderBy(x => x.Segments.Length);

    containerList.Add(new UriContainer()
                      {
                          Parent = sorted.First(),
                          Children = sorted.Skip(1).ToList()
                      });
}
```

The above code will give you a structure like this:

```
http://x.com/
    http://x.com/y
    http://x.com/y/w
    http://x.com/y/z
----------------------
http://a.com/b/c
    http://a.com/b/c/d
    http://a.com/b/c/e
----------------------
```

This code has very little error prevention, you might want to make sure items are not null and such but it at least gives you a starting point.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ysphj)